# How to replace empty cell of a CSV with text as NULL using Java

Tags: java, csv

I have input CSV. One of the columns has no value in the cell. While writing the data to another CSV I want to write NULL in that empty cell.
I tried to replace "" with NULL but then it prints NULL in all cells.
Also, I want to exclude adding NULL text in hard-coded columns of the code i.e. UniqueId, IsDelete, Rootpid. I want them to be empty.

[image: Input]
[image: Expected Output]

Here is my code so far:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
    {


        String sourceFilePath = "C://MyData/Emp_Input.csv";
        String newFilePath = "C://MyData/Emp_Output.csv";
        File sourceCsvFile = new File(sourceFilePath);
        File finalCsvFile = new File(newFilePath);
        final Charset Encoding = Charset.forName("UTF-8"); 
        String cvsSplitBy = ",";


        String line = "";

        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(finalCsvFile), Encoding));


        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(sourceCsvFile))) 
        {
            line = br.readLine(); 
            String newFileLine = "UniqueID" + cvsSplitBy +line + cvsSplitBy  + "IsDelete" + cvsSplitBy + "Rootpid";
            writer.write(newFileLine);   
            writer.newLine();


            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)  
            {   
            /*  if (line.contains("") )
                {

                    line = line.replace("", "NULL"); // missing code to replace empty cell of a csv with text as NULL
                } */


                else if (line.contains("TRUE") || line.contains("FALSE"))
                {
                    line = line.replace("TRUE", "1");
                    line = line.replace("FALSE", "0");

                } 


                    newFileLine =  cvsSplitBy + line + cvsSplitBy + cvsSplitBy;
                    writer.write(newFileLine);  
                    writer.newLine();


            }

            writer.close();

        }


    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible, there is no difference between empty and null strings in csv.

Comment: Agreed! But I have a requirement for further process of the application I want NULL as a text to be written in those cells which are empty.

Comment: You can configure excel to show NULL for empty strings in your csv, but if you write null in cvs, it's the value "null" which is of course different from empty and null object

Comment: Yes I want value null to be written in CSV.